# For any float number x,y,integer n, where const y=n-x, and 0<=x,y,n<=MAX_VALUE, is x+y==n always true?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

For example:

```js
const n=5;
const x=1.23;
const y=n-x;
document.write(x+y==n);
```

the code about prints true for n=5,x=1.23,y=5-1.23 (value after rounded). I think it is just a "lucky" case to be true because I think there may some case that n-x would round to something so that x+y would not be equal to n again. But I try using for loop to find some false case:

```js
for(let i=0;i<100000;i++){
  const n=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
  const x=Math.random()*5000;
  const y=n-x;
  if(x+y!=n){
    document.write(x+","+y+","+n);
    break;
  }
}
```

and surprisingly don't print any exceptions for several times running.

So my question is, for any float number x,y,integer n, where const y=n-x, and o<=x,y,n<=MAX_VALUE, is x+y==n always true? If so, what is the reason? Is there any case that is false?

Side note: It seems that it is also true for x>n,eg:

```js
for(let i=0;i<100000;i++){
      const n=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
      const x=10000+Math.random()*5000;
      const y=n-x;
      if(x+y!=n){
        document.write(x+","+y+","+n);
        break;
      }
}
```

but not in the case that x is negative:

```js
for(let i=0;i<100000;i++){
      const n=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
      const x=Math.random()*-5000;
      const y=n-x;
      if(x+y!=n){
        document.write(x+","+y+","+n);
        break;
      }
}
```

What is the reason?

Comment: values around 2**±52 are often where interesting things happen with 64bit IEEE754 binary floats, as that's where you start running out of precision.  printing out values in "hex format" can help, `js-hexfloat` is the best I could find in JS, in C it's the `%a` conversion when using `printf`, [`std::hexfloat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) in C++ or `float.hex()` in Python

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't. Here's a counter-example:

```js
const n=5847425060810559;
const x=87667.5;
const y=n-x;
document.write(x+y==n);
document.write("<br>lhs = " + (x+y) + "<br>rhs = " + n);
```

Comment: `n = 2**52 + 1; x = 0.5` and `n = 2**53 + 2; x = 1` are counter-examples where it might be easier to see what's going on